# flex links html in tooltip

Tags: apache-flex, tooltip

i'm using flex sdk 3.6
i'm using a tooltip on a datagrid.
this tooltip is html with some HTTP links.
when i move mouse over tooltip tooltip disappear

may be some idea?

my tooltip source code

```
package com
{
    import mx.controls.ToolTip;

    public class HTMLToolTip extends ToolTip
    {
        public function HTMLToolTip()
        {    super(); }


        override protected function commitProperties():void{
            super.commitProperties();
            textField.htmlText = text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your can custom the itemRenderer and the tooltip renderer, then watch the MOUSE_OUT and MOUSE_OVER events.

i package this functions in a class.

```
public class ToolTipUtil
{
    /**
     * register a tip
     * 
     * @param target
     * @param toolTipClazz
     * 
     */     
    public static function registerTipsClass(target:IUIComponent, toolTipClazz:Class):void
    {
        var toolTip:IUIComponent = new toolTipClazz();
        registerTips(target, toolTip);
    }

    /**
     * register a tip
     * 
     * @param target
     * @param toolTip
     * 
     */     
    public static function registerTips(target:IUIComponent, toolTip:IUIComponent):void
    {
        toolTip.visible = false;
        PopUpManager.addPopUp(toolTip, DisplayObject(target));

        target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, function mouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (!toolTip.visible)
            {
                toolTip.visible = true;
                showTipsOnMouse(target, toolTip);
            }
        });

        target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, function mouseOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (toolTip.visible)
                toolTip.visible = false;
        });
    }

    /**
     * toolTip show on the target
     *  
     * @param target IUIComponent
     * @param toolTip IUIComponent
     * 
     */     
    public static function showTipsOnTarget(target:IUIComponent, toolTip:IUIComponent):void
    {
        var height:Number = target.height;
        var systemManager:ISystemManager = target.systemManager;
        // Calculate global position of label.
        var sm:ISystemManager = systemManager.topLevelSystemManager;
        var sbRoot:DisplayObject = sm.getSandboxRoot();
        var screen:Rectangle;
        var pt:Point = new Point(0, 0);
        pt = target.localToGlobal(pt);
        pt = sbRoot.globalToLocal(pt);          

        toolTip.move(pt.x, pt.y + (height - toolTip.height) / 2);

        if (sm != sbRoot)
        {
            var request:InterManagerRequest = new InterManagerRequest(InterManagerRequest.SYSTEM_MANAGER_REQUEST, 
                false, false,
                "getVisibleApplicationRect"); 
            sbRoot.dispatchEvent(request);
            screen = Rectangle(request.value);
        }
        else
            screen = sm.getVisibleApplicationRect();

        var screenRight:Number = screen.x + screen.width;
        pt.x = toolTip.x;
        pt.y = toolTip.y;
        pt = sbRoot.localToGlobal(pt);
        if (pt.x + toolTip.width > screenRight)
            toolTip.move(toolTip.x - (pt.x + toolTip.width - screenRight), toolTip.y);
    }

    /**
     * toolTip show under the mouse
     *  
     * @param target IUIComponent
     * @param toolTip IUIComponent
     * 
     */     
    public static function showTipsOnMouse(target:IUIComponent, toolTip:IUIComponent):void
    {
        var systemManager:ISystemManager = target.systemManager;
        var sm:ISystemManager = systemManager.topLevelSystemManager;
        var sbRoot:DisplayObject = sm.getSandboxRoot();

        var screenWidth:Number = systemManager.screen.width;
        var screenHeight:Number = systemManager.screen.height;
        // Position the upper-left of the tooltip
        // at the lower-right of the arrow cursor.
        var x:Number = DisplayObject(systemManager).mouseX + 11;
        var y:Number = DisplayObject(systemManager).mouseY + 22;

        // If the tooltip is too wide to fit onstage, move it left.
        var toolTipWidth:Number = toolTip.width;
        if (x + toolTipWidth > screenWidth)
            x = screenWidth - toolTipWidth;

        // If the tooltip is too tall to fit onstage, move it up.
        var toolTipHeight:Number = toolTip.height;
        if (y + toolTipHeight > screenHeight)
            y = screenHeight - toolTipHeight;

        var pos:Point = new Point(x, y);
        pos = DisplayObject(systemManager).localToGlobal(pos);
        pos = DisplayObject(sbRoot).globalToLocal(pos);
        toolTip.move(pos.x, pos.y);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you add a sample to use it in a datagrid, in my program used ToolTipManager.toolTipClass =ToolTipUtil; but nothing appears, thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this, it will only create one HTMLToolTip, then if you want change the content when mouse over the different rows, you can set the HTMLToolTip's data to change the content.

```
private var htmlToolTip:HTMLToolTip = new HTMLToolTip();

        protected function datagrid1_itemRollOverHandler(event:ListEvent):void
        {
            ToolTipUtil.showTipsOnMouse(event.itemRenderer, htmlToolTip);
            htmlToolTip.data = event.itemRenderer.data;
            htmlToolTip.visible = true; 
        }

        protected function datagrid1_itemRollOutHandler(event:ListEvent):void
        {
            htmlToolTip.visible = false;                
        }

        protected function datagrid1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            htmlToolTip.visible = false;
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(htmlToolTip, Application.application as DisplayObject);
        }

<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{dataArray}" itemRollOver="datagrid1_itemRollOverHandler(event)"
             itemRollOut="datagrid1_itemRollOutHandler(event)"
             creationComplete="datagrid1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Title" dataField="label">
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Comment: when i move mouse to tooltip it disappear. it not work for me

Comment: does the tooltip's content will change when datagrid mouse over the itemRenderer, or just the datagrid's tooltip? you can just when mouse over the datagird, then show tooltip, the tooltip add FlexMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_OUTSIDE listner to hide tooltip

Comment: tooltip change when i move mouse on another row in datagrid